# Select from 'view' causing execution timeout in PHP and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, executiontimeout

I have created a `view` called `stats` that selects the sum of records that adhere to a certain attribute

```
CREATE VIEW stats
AS
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN attribute = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS attribute1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN attribute = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS attribute2
FROM table
GO
```

The view is created fine and when I say `SELECT * FROM stats` in SQL Server Management Studio the results show up fine.

The problem is when I use PHP to grab the data:

```
$GRAB_STATS_DATA = $DBH->query("SELECT * FROM stats");
while($row = $GRAB_STATS_DATA->fetch()){
    $attribute1 = $row['attribute1'];
    ... // and so on
}
```

I get an error saying `[PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\ ... on line 17]`

Why does the above timeout using PHP (or take longer than 300sec to execute) but display fine in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: it could be that you are not communicating well with your DB server?

Comment: @AresDraguna, please elaborate? All other comms with DB are good.

Comment: place a die() right before the grabbing. so right before while() to see if you exceed the time before on in while

Comment: @AresDraguna, ok, I added `die()` just before the `while()` and the page refreshes fast, only the information is not displayed. So it seems that the time is exceeded before the `while()`?

Comment: PDO? Use `foreach($GRAB_STATS_DATA->fetchAll() as $row){`

Comment: Ah, this seems to have solved it. Why is this?

Comment: Because `while($row = $GRAB_STATS_DATA->fetch()){` is always true and got infinite loop

Comment: @trzyeM post that as an answer with some documentation (for other newbies :D ) so that proPhet can accept your answer :)

Comment: @proPhet, do the right thing and accept the man's answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
foreach ($GRAB_STATS_DATA->fetchAll() as $row){
  $attribute1 = $row['attribute1'];
    ... // and so on
}
```